# unique_ptr basic implementation for single objects

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

This is an implementation to simulate the basic functionality of `unique_ptr`.
This doesn't provide features like custom deleter and `make_unique()`.

I would really appreciate any feedback to improve the below code, any other api's that I should be providing etc.

**my_unique_ptr.h**

```
#ifndef MY_UNIQUE_PTR_H_
#define MY_UNIQUE_PTR_H_

#include <utility>

namespace kapil {
  template <typename T>
  class unique_ptr final {
    private:
      T* ptr_;
      unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;               // Make unique_ptr non copy constructible
      unique_ptr& operator = (const unique_ptr&) = delete;  // Make unique_ptr non copy assignable

    public:
      explicit unique_ptr (T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept
        : ptr_{ptr} { }

      unique_ptr(unique_ptr<T>&& rval) noexcept               // Move constructor
        : ptr_{rval.ptr_} {
        rval.ptr_ = nullptr;
      }

      unique_ptr& operator = (unique_ptr&& rhs) noexcept {   // Move assignment
        delete ptr_;
        ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;
        rhs.ptr_ = nullptr;
        return *this;
      }

      ~unique_ptr() noexcept {
        delete ptr_;
      }


      T* release() noexcept {
        T* old_ptr = ptr_;
        ptr_ = nullptr;
        return old_ptr;
      }

      void reset(T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept {
        delete ptr_;
        ptr_ = ptr;
      }

      void swap(unique_ptr& rhs) noexcept {
        std::swap(ptr_, rhs.ptr_);
      }

      T* get() const noexcept {
        return ptr_;
      }

      explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return (ptr_ != nullptr);
      }

      T& operator * () const {
        return *ptr_;
      }

      T* operator -> () const noexcept {
        return ptr_;
      }

      friend bool operator == (const unique_ptr& lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs) {
        return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
      }

      friend bool operator != (const unique_ptr& lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs) {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
      }
  };

  template <typename T>
  void swap(unique_ptr<T>& lhs, unique_ptr<T>& rhs) {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
  }
} //kapil

#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't mark your class `final` without a good reason. It inhibits user-freedom.
2. The default-access for members of a `class` is already `private`.
3. Explicitly deleting [copy-constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and [copy-assignment-operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) is superfluous, as you define move-constructor and move-assignment, which *already* suppresses them. Still, some assert being explicit adds clarity.
4. I wonder why you didn't declare construction from `T*` to be `constexpr`...
5. Try to consistently use the injected class-name (`unique_ptr`), instead of sporadically naming the template-arguments (`unique_ptr<T>`).
6. You are missing implicit upcasting in the move-ctor and move-assignment-operator.

   ```
   template <class U, class = std::enable_if_t<
       std::has_virtual_destructor<T>() && std::is_convertible<U*, T*>()>>
   unique_ptr(unique_ptr<U>&& other) noexcept
   : ptr_(other.release())
   {}

   template <class U>
   auto operator=(std::unique_ptr<U>&& other) noexcept
   -> decltype((*this = unique_ptr(other))) {
       return *this = unique_ptr(other);
   }
   ```
7. Take a look at [`std::exchange(object, value)` from `<utility>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange). It allows you to simplify some of your code.
8. If you use move-and-swap, you could isolate freeing of the referee to the dtor. Having it at only one place ensures you always do it the same, and is a good first step for retrofitting custom deleters. Not to mention that it in many cases simplifies the implementation.
9. `(ptr != nullptr)` can be simplified to `ptr`. In contexts where you have to force the type, `!!ptr`.
10. Why are `op==()` and `op!=()` inline-friend-functions, but `swap()` isn't? That's inconsistent. It's especially puzzling as they are all written to use the public interface only.
11. There is exactly one place where you don't have a single empty line between two functions, but two. Yes, that's nothing big.